# HTML table offset one column

Tags: html, css, html-table

How can I offset one column in a table row? I've used colspan but it takes two columns width, but I want to like this image.

[image]

Here is my code:

```css
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

th, td {
    padding: 5px 15px;
    text-align: left;    
}
```

```html
<table> 
    <tr> 
        <th colspan="2">65</th> <th colspan="2">40</th> 
        <th colspan="2">20</th> 
    </tr> 
    <tr> 
        <th>Men</th> 
        <th>Women</th> 
        <th>Men</th> 
        <th>Women</th> 
        <th>Men</th> 
        <th>Women</th> 
    </tr> 
    <tr> 
         <td>85</td> 
         <td>78</td> 
         <td>82</td> 
         <td>77</td> 
         <td>81</td> 
    </tr> 
</table>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your HTML markup isn't valid with the missing `<td>` element on the third row. You get the following warning on the HTML checker:

> A table row was 5 columns wide, which is less than the column count established by the first row (6).

So you have to set a (empty) cell, but you can hide this cell with CSS. To hide the empty cell you can use the [`:empty`](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#empty-pseudo) and [`:blank`](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#blank-pseudo) (is a draft at the moment) pseudo-classes. There is no need to set a class for the empty cell.

```css
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
th, td {
  padding: 5px 15px;
  text-align: left;    
}
td:empty {
  visibility:hidden;
}
td:blank {
  visibility:hidden;
}
```

```html
<table> 
  <tr> 
    <th colspan="2">65</th>
    <th colspan="2">40</th> 
    <th colspan="2">20</th> 
  </tr> 
  <tr> 
    <th>Men</th> 
    <th>Women</th> 
    <th>Men</th> 
    <th>Women</th> 
    <th>Men</th> 
    <th>Women</th> 
  </tr> 
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>85</td> 
    <td>78</td> 
    <td>82</td> 
    <td>77</td> 
    <td>81</td> 
  </tr> 
</table>
```

Answer (score 4):

```css
th, td {

  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;

}
th, td {
  padding: 5px 15px;
  text-align: left; 
vertical-align:top;   
}

td.empty{ border: 0;}
```

```html
    <table cellspacing="0"> 
        <tr> 
            <th colspan="2">65</th> <th colspan="2">40</th> 
            <th colspan="2">20</th> 
        </tr> 
        <tr> 
            <th>Men</th> 
            <th>Women</th> 
            <th>Men</th> 
            <th>Women</th> 
            <th>Men</th> 
            <th>Women</th> 
        </tr> 
        <tr> 
            <td class="empty"></td> 
            <td>85</td> 
            <td>78</td> 
            <td>82</td> 
            <td>77</td> 
            <td>81</td> 
        </tr> 
    </table>
```